# KVM or Virtualbox for development?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I have to port some Linux applications to Windows. For that purpose I want to install Windows in a virtual environment. Which one would you recommend, KVM or Virtualbox? Configuration is not a problem, the focus lies primarily on performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, they're both free, you can try both, and I'd choose the one that you prefer after trying them both out. Nothing to lose but time, and most people tend to advise using the best tool for the job, which includes as part of the criteria what you're most comfortable using and like.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd try VMWare Server, Windows runs very well on it, it's mature and free.

Comment: ...and the slowest performance of all three.  once a colleage made the mistake of porting a few low-load servers to it in an emergency.  all our users complained immediately about performance.  we had to borrow another machine and put KVM on it to stop complains.

Comment: VirtualBox is better then vmware ESXI and server.
VirtualBox is more light-weight and easy to use.

Comment: @SilverNight, that's a stupid thing to say - ESXi is wildly different to both VMWare Server and Virtualbox - they do totally different things, also "easy to use" is a subjective thing. Please try to formulate your comments and answers better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox used to have better Windows drivers available than KVM, so that's what I would try first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VMWare Player also but VirtualBox is more flexible and that is a plus for development. If you need to run some server for web hosting or running some sql server or other back-end then VMWare Server could be a better option. Or ESXi if you got the right hardware.